# Inverse relationship test in junit

Tags: java, junit

I have following method which returns the value which appear most in a list

```
public Integer notaFrecventaMaxima() {
    if (note.size() == 0) {
        return null;
    } else {
        Map<Integer, Integer> frecventaNote = new HashMap();
        for (Integer nota : this.note) {
            Integer frecventaNota = frecventaNote.get(nota);
            frecventaNote.put(nota, frecventaNota == null ? 1 : frecventaNota+1);
        }

        Entry<Integer, Integer> max = null;
        for (Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : frecventaNote.entrySet()) {
            if (max == null || entry.getValue() > max.getValue()) {
                max = entry;
            }
        }

        Integer maxValue = max.getValue();

        int returnNota = frecventaNote.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> entry.getValue() == maxValue)
                .map(entry -> entry.getKey()).max(Comparator.naturalOrder()).get();

        return returnNota;
    }
}
```

I need to make an inverse relationship junit test for this method, but i dont know how it's possible. Could you give me any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the computations within this method are (in the end) based on what

```
for (Integer nota : this.note) {
```

provides as "input data".

In other words: your class under tests seems to contain an array/list/... with Integer objects. This data is used to create a HashMap and to make computations; which will result (in the end) as a single Integer value.

Thus testing is actually pretty simple: you create **different** objects of your class under test, where you push "different" values into `note`.

Then you call that method; and depending on the result that you would expect for each of those input sets; you simply assert of the value coming back to you is the expected one:

```
@Test
public void testCasaUno() {
  Whatever underTest = new Whatever(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4));
  assertThat(underTest.notaFrecventaMaxima(), is(42));
```

}

Of course: writing such tests might be tricky, because you have "compute" the expected result for a certain input manually in your head. That is a lot of work.

I would rather advise you to improve the quality of your production code by dissecting it into more methods. Example: you could move the creation + setup for that Map into its **own** method. And now ... you can *test* that method on its own, much easier: here list goes in, just check if the outgoing map looks like you expect it.

And so on ...  as so often: the more your production code follows "clean code" rules; the easier it will be to test.